# How to exit ell.stackexchange.com profile and enter another?

Tags: discussion

Sorry for off topic, but I don't really see how to exit ell.stackexchange.com profile and enter another

How can I exit ellstackexchangecom profile and enter another?

Answer (score 1):

Select **log out** from the top right menu, then log in with the other profile.